# How I can upload file to google drive with google drive api?

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I did as in the documentation (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#http---single-request), but it doesn't work:

```
          var fileMetadata = {
            name: e.target.files[j].name,
            parents: this.currentDirectoryId ? [this.currentDirectoryId] : []
          }
          var media = {
            mimeType: e.target.files[j].type,
            body: e.target.files[j]
          }
          window.gapi.client.drive.files.create({
            resource: fileMetadata,
            media: media,
            fields: 'id, name, mimeType, createdTime'
          }).then(res => console.log(res))
```

File is created, but empty and named "Untitled" with mimeType "application/octet-stream"

Comment: If the name is wrong then fix  name: e.target.files[j].name,   Theres really now way we can help you debug the name as you did not include the code that generates it

Comment: The name is generated correctly, the problem is not e.target.files[j].name/

Comment: Most likely the very structure of the request is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Issue and workaround:

- When I tested `gapi.client.drive.files.create`, it seems that although this method can create new file with the metadata, the file content cannot be included. So in this answer, in order to upload a file by including the file metadata, I would like to propose to upload a file with `multipart/form-data` using `fetch` of Javascript. In this case, the access token is retrieved by `gapi.auth.getToken().access_token`.
- Unfortunately, from your script, I couldn't understand about `e.target`. So in this sample script, I would like to propose the sample script for uploading a file, which is retrieved from the input tag, with the metadata.

### Sample script:

#### HTML side:

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="file">
```

#### Javascript side:

```
const files = document.getElementById("files").files;

const file = files[0];
const fr = new FileReader();
fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
fr.onload = (f) => {
  const fileMetadata = {
    name: file.name,
    parents: this.currentDirectoryId ? [this.currentDirectoryId] : []  // This is from your script.
  }
  const form = new FormData();
  form.append('metadata', new Blob([JSON.stringify(fileMetadata)], {type: 'application/json'}));
  form.append('file', new Blob([new Uint8Array(f.target.result)], {type: file.type}));
  fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: new Headers({'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + gapi.auth.getToken().access_token}),
    body: form
  }).then(res => res.json()).then(res => console.log(res));
};
```

- In this script, the file retrieved from `input` tag is uploaded to Google Drive with `multipart/form-data`.

### Note:

- In this script, it supposes that your authorization script can be used for uploading a file to Google Drive. Please be careful this.
- In this answer, as a sample script, the file is uploaded with `uploadType=multipart`. In this case, the maximum file size is 5 MB. Please be careful this. When you want to upload the file with the large size, please check the resumable upload. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#resumable)

### References:

- [Using Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)
- [Files: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create)
- [Upload file data](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads)
- [Perform a resumable upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#resumable)

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I wanted to do.

Comment: @Mikhail Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.