# How can I upload files to google drive that are in a url?

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-javascript-client

I try to upload a photo that I have in a URL on another server, but it does not work for me or I do not know how to upload them in this case I am going to upload a photo but I also want to upload files that will upload to that URL.

```js
const img = await fetch("http://example.com/api/photo")

await gapi.client.drive.files.create({
  resource: {
    name: "New Folder",
    body: img,
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

The simple anwser is you cant do it like that. The file being [Uploaded](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads) must be sent in the form of a stream

Download the file to your own machine and then upload it from there. Or try to figure out how to turn your url into a stream.

```
var fileMetadata = {
  'name': 'photo.jpg'
};
var media = {
  mimeType: 'image/jpeg',
  body: fs.createReadStream('files/photo.jpg')
};
drive.files.create({
  resource: fileMetadata,
  media: media,
  fields: 'id'
}, function (err, file) {
  if (err) {
    // Handle error
    console.error(err);
  } else {
    console.log('File Id: ', file.id);
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm doing it in frontend js so instead of fs I can use formData or bunno pass it to base64 right?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to download an image data from an URL, and want to upload the downloaded image data to Google Drive.

  - From your script, the image data is downloaded by `const img = await fetch("http://example.com/api/photo")`.
- You want to achieve this using [googleapis for Javascript](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client).

#### Modification points:

- In this case, it retrieves Blob of image data from `fetch`, and the blob is uploaded to Google Drive.
- Unfortunately, in the current stage, it seems that although googleapis for Javascript can create new file with the metadata, the file content cannot be included. By this, in this answer, I use the method of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65192321). The downloaded image data is uploaded using `fetch` with `multipart/form-data`.

When above poiints are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
const img = await fetch("http://example.com/api/photo").then((e) => e.blob());

const fileMetadata = {name: "sampleName"}; // Please set filename.
const form = new FormData();
form.append('metadata', new Blob([JSON.stringify(fileMetadata)], {type: 'application/json'}));
form.append('file', img);
fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: new Headers({'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + gapi.auth.getToken().access_token}),
  body: form
}).then(res => res.json()).then(res => console.log(res));
```

- By this modification, the downloaded image data is uploaded to Google Drive with `multipart/form-data`.

#### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes as follows.

  - Your URL of `http://example.com/api/photo` is the direct link of the image data.
  - Your authorization script can be used for uploading a file to Google Drive.
- In this answer, as a sample script, the file is uploaded with `uploadType=multipart`. In this case, the maximum file size is 5 MB. Please be careful this. When you want to upload the file with the large size, please check the resumable upload. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#resumable)

#### References:

- [Google API Client Library for JavaScript](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client)
- [Using Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)
- [Files: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create)
- [Upload file data](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads)
- Related question

  - [How I can upload file to google drive with google drive api?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65181932)